# I've "broken" Excel - copy & paste behaviour changed. A simple fix for anyone who knows what I've done

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I've clearly hit some hotkey in Excel, and have odd copy/paste behaviour now.

The green dotted line that appears around cells when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> them is now permanent.

Normally it disappears once you paste somewhere, or if you move to another cell and edit it, or hit delete in an empty cell.  Now the only way I can get rid of it is to hit escape.

What have I done, and how can I revert to the "normal" behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behaviour and a (hugely fundamental) change that Microsoft have made to Excel:

https://winbuzzer.com/2017/06/01/microsoft-finally-brings-fast-ring-update-office-insiders-windows-xcxwbn/

> "Keep the copy: Copy your cells and, before you paste, you can still do other tasks like typing or inserting cells."

I don't feel I was notified of this change (but maybe I was and dismissed/ignored it).  Either way it certainly wasn't made abundantly clear to me.  There should also be an opt-out for it, and doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on 'esc', it will deselect the cells after pasting. A pain, though, for sure!